# Thread isn't pausing when pause button is clicked

Tags: java, multithreading, button

I am trying to pause a bouncing ball animation when the user clicks the pause button and resume it when they click resume. The problem is when I click the pause button it should be setting the suspendRequested to true so it enters the if statement and runs the while statement which causes the thread to wait which stops the ball from animating. Then when the user clicks resume it should set it back to false which breaks it out of the while loop and it continues to animate. This does not occur so why it isn't breaking out of the loop?

```
class BallRunnable implements Runnable
{
   private Lock suspendLock = new ReentrantLock();
   private Condition suspendCondition = suspendLock.newCondition();
   private volatile boolean suspendRequested = false;
   private boolean isBouncing = true;
   private Ball ball;
   private Component component;
   public static final int STEPS = 1000;
   public static final int DELAY = 100;

   /**
    * Constructs the runnable.
    * @param aBall the ball to bounce
    * @param aComponent the component in which the ball bounces
    */
   public BallRunnable()
   {
   }
   public BallRunnable(Ball aBall, Component aComponent)
   {
      ball = aBall;
      component = aComponent;
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(isBouncing())
      {
          try
          {
                ball.move(component.getBounds());
                component.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Ball is bouncing " + name);
                if(suspendRequested)
                {
                    suspendLock.lock();
                    System.out.println("Locking thread");
                    try
                    {
                        while(suspendRequested)
                        {
                            System.out.println("About to await");
                            suspendCondition.await();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                     suspendLock.unlock();
                     System.out.println("Unlocked " + name);
                    }
                }
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
          }

        }
    }

    public boolean isBouncing()
    {
        if(isBouncing)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setBouncing(boolean b)
    {
        isBouncing = b;
    }

   public void requestSuspend()
   {
       suspendRequested = true;
   }

   public void requestResume()
   {
       suspendRequested = false;
       suspendLock.lock();
       try
       {
           suspendCondition.signalAll();
       }
       finally
       {
           suspendLock.unlock();
       }
   }

}
```

Here it is supposed to pause and resume the thread when the buttons are clicked but it doesn't break them out of the loop. If the boolean that makes it look is set to true and then the user presses pause to change it to false shouldn't it break it out of the loop?

```
class BounceFrame extends JFrame
{
   BallRunnable br = new BallRunnable();
   private BallComponent comp;

   /**
    * Constructs the frame with the component for showing the bouncing ball and Start and Close
    * buttons
    */
   public BounceFrame()
   {
      comp = new BallComponent();
      add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      addButton(buttonPanel, "Start", new ActionListener()
         {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
               addBall();
               //Don't let user click again
               System.out.println("Clicked start");
            }
         });

    addButton(buttonPanel, "Pause", new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {

            System.out.println("Clicked Paused");
            br.setBouncing(false);
            System.out.println("Clicked Paused STOP BOUNCinG");
            br.requestSuspend();
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Clicked Paused REQUEST SUSPEND " + name);
        }
    });

    addButton(buttonPanel, "Resume", new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("Clicked Resume");
                br.setBouncing(true);
                br.requestResume();
            }
    });

      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      pack();
   }
```

This is homework so I'm not looking for a solution but what is it I'm not seeing about breaking out of the loop when the pause button is clicked?

Comment: I'm concerned that it's possible that the `isBouncing` may be processed before the `suspendRequested`, meaning that the `run` method will exit, making it impossible to resume

Comment: I run your code without issue.  I did move the `suspendRequested` check above the `Thread.sleep`, but I can't see that making any difference, seems the problem may be else where

Answer (score 0):

So Actually i used the timer object, when you press the button timer will start, if you again clicked than it will stop, you need to make a timer class for you bouncing ball. Actually i used the mouse Pressed action performed method, but it is same thing

```
if (myTimer.isRunning())
    {
     myTimer.stop();
    }
    else
    {
     myTimer.start();
    }
    }
    });
```