# how can i pause the ball when button click

Tags: android, android-animation

This code gives ball moving all directions on the screen when i click on ball. My requirement is that I want to pause the  ball when I click pause button ?  For that where should I need to add button and what is the code to pause the ball ?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
static TextView editText;
static int score=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
     editText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     //editText.setText(""+score);
     Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AnimatedView(MainActivity.this).pauseClicked();
        }
    });
}
public static void setCount(int count) {

    //new MainActivity().onCreate(null);
    score=count;
    editText.setText(""+score);
}
```

}

Animatedview.java

```
public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{


static int count=0;
private Context mContext;
int x = 130;
int y = 470;
private float a,b;
private int xVelocity = 8;
private int yVelocity = 8;
private Handler h;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 25;
BitmapDrawable ball;
boolean touching;
boolean dm_touched = false;
float move=3;
int bm_x = 0, bm_y = 0, bm_offsetx, bm_offsety,bm_w,bm_h;
boolean paused;
private Paint line, ball1, background;
static int click=0;
public AnimatedView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    mContext = context;  
    h = new Handler();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    int bgColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.game_bg);
    String bgColorStr = prefs.getString("bgColor","");
    if(bgColorStr.length() > 0) {
        bgColor = Color.parseColor(bgColorStr);
    }
    int lineColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.line);
    String lineColorStr = prefs.getString("wallColor","");
    if(lineColorStr.length() > 0) {
        lineColor = Color.parseColor(lineColorStr);
    }
    int ballColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.position);
    String ballColorStr = prefs.getString("ballColor","");
    if(ballColorStr.length() > 0) {
        ballColor = Color.parseColor(ballColorStr);
    }

    line = new Paint();
    line.setColor(lineColor);
    ball1 = new Paint();
    ball1.setColor(ballColor);
    background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(bgColor);
    setFocusable(true);
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
} 


@Override
public void buildDrawingCache() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.buildDrawingCache();
}
private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Log.e("game","run called");
        if(touching = true)
        invalidate(); 
    }
};


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  
    //Log.e("game","ondraw called");
    //int z= c.getHeight()/2;
    //Log.e("game","z is"+z);

    BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
    if (x<0 && y <0) {
        //x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = c.getHeight()/2;


    } else {
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;
        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
        }
        if (y >( this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) ||y <0) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
        }
    }
    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null); 
        if(touching){
         // Log.e("game","iftouch called called");
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
        bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
      }
  }

public void pauseClicked()
{   touching=true;
    Log.d("s","pause called");
    if (touching) {
        // paused = true;
        Log.d("s","touhcing called");
        h.removeCallbacks(r);
        touching = false;
    } else {
        touching = true;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Log.d("game","ontouch called");
    int touchType = event.getAction();

     switch(touchType){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            a = event.getX();
            b = event.getY();
            touching = true;

           /* if (dm_touched) {
                x = (int) a - bm_offsetx;
                y = (int) b - bm_offsety;
            }*/
            //invalidate();
            break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
             //x and y give you your touch coordinates
              a = event.getX();
              b = event.getY();
              touching = true;
             /* if (touching) {
                    // paused = true;
                    h.removeCallbacks(r);
                    touching = false;
                } else {
                    touching = true;
                }*/
              //Log.d("game","action_down called");
              Log.e("s",""+ a);
              Log.e("s",""+ b);
              Log.e("s",""+ x);
              Log.e("s",""+ y);
              Log.e("s",""+ bm_w);
              Log.e("s",""+ bm_h);
              if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                  count++;
                MainActivity.setCount(count);
                  //invalidate();
                  Log.i("score",""+count);

                }
              if (dm_touched) {
                  if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                  move+=2;
                    //x = (int) a - bm_offsetx;
                  y = (int) (yVelocity*-1);

                  //invalidate();

                }}
               // dm_touched = true;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             a = event.getX();
              b = event.getY();
             if(a>x+20&&a<330&&b<=y+320&&b>y){
                 click++;

             invalidate();
             touching=true;}
             if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                Log.e("game","clicked");
            }

            default:

                dm_touched = true;
            }

            return true;
}

@Override
public void destroyDrawingCache() {

    count=0;
    super.destroyDrawingCache();
}
```

}

Comment: I think this could Help You 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776645/thread-isnt-pausing-when-pause-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause the ball when user again touch  on the screen if it suits your requirement.
For that you can implement like this in your MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN event :

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // x and y give you your touch coordinates
                a = event.getX();
                b = event.getY();
                if (touching) {
                    // paused = true;
                    h.removeCallbacks(r);
                    touching = false;
                } else {
                    touching = true;
                }
                Log.e("s", "" + a);
                Log.e("s", "" + b);
                Log.e("s", "" + x);
                Log.e("s", "" + y);
                Log.e("s", "" + bm_w);
                Log.e("s", "" + bm_h);
                if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) {
                    count++;

                    Log.i("score", "" + count);

                }
                if (dm_touched) {
                    if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) {
                        move += 2;

                        y = yVelocity * -1;

                    }
                }
```

So that whenever user touch next time on screen ball will be paused there.And remove `touching = true;` from your Action.MOVE event.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: excellent job thank u andim,ok image stopped when user again touch on the screen same code how can i use with button

Comment: You can put button on the screen anywhere.Take touching as a global variable And onClick of button you can put condition for remove callbacks from Handler.Take necessary variable as Global Variable.

Comment: i did same thing what u said, i add the button top the screen in my mainactivity.java and i write pauseclicked method in animatedview with condition for remove callbacks from Handler.but when i click pause button system crashed,i updated the total code in above question please check it and thanks a lot for ur response